# Compare 2 columns from different tables and return different values of 2nd table

Tags: php, html, mysql, comparison, join

I have two tables. Second table has a column that stores the primary id of the First table. I want to return different rows from the first table that are not in the second table.

**example Table 1**

```
id/
 12. value 1
 21. value 2
 34. value 3
 41. value 4
```

**second table**

```
id/    
 1. value 12
 2. value 6
 3. value 41
```

I want to return the opposite rows in table one where the values match from second table; e.g return value 2 and 3 in this example from table 1 where id is not 12 or 41.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like something you should do directly in the query. Your question is a bit unclear, bit if you want to get all rows from table 1 whose ids are not stored in table 2, you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table2)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much, rattled my brain for few hours.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLE2)